# Contents of the map are not getting printed in specific manner

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap

In this program I am trying to rearrange {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1} and print the order {0,0,1,1,1,1}.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void segregate0and1(int arr[], int size){
std::map<int,int> mymap;
for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
    std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
    //cout<<"Array element"<<arr[i]<<endl;
    it = mymap.find(arr[i]);
    if (it != mymap.end()){
        mymap[arr[i]]++;
        }
        else{
         mymap.insert ( std::pair<int,int>(arr[i],1) );    
        }

    }

cout<<"Printing after segregating"<<endl;
std::map<int,int>::iterator it1;
int j,k;
for (it1=mymap.begin(); it1!=mymap.end(); it1++){
    k = it1->first;
    j = it1->second;
    //cout<<"The value of k is "<<k<<endl;
    //cout<<"The value of j is "<<j<<endl;
    while (j > 0){
        //cout<<"I am inside this";
        std::cout<<k<<" ";
        j--;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    segregate0and1(arr, arr_size);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the map is getting populated correctly and the problem lies while printing the map out so that the array is re-arranged in an segregated manner. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong with the piece of code. I have given the working code. Can somebody point out what the error is?

Comment: You shown the "input" and the expected "output", but what is the *actual* output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: By the way you don't need that `find` or `if .. else`. Just doing `mymap[arr[i]]++` should work just fine ("indexing" a map creates the element if it doesn't exist, with a default value which is zero for `int`).

Comment: I got the error. I was not using correct C++ compiler, when I used (-std=c++11) then it worked. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> In this program I am trying to rearrange {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1} and print
>   the order {0,0,1,1,1,1}.

From your words you need to `sort` `elements` of the `array`.
You can use `std::sort` function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 };

    std::cout << "Before" << std::endl;
    for (int nVal : arr)
        std::cout << nVal << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    //Sort it
    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    std::cout << "After" << std::endl;
    for (int nVal : arr)
        std::cout << nVal << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before
0 1 0 1 1 1
After
0 0 1 1 1 1
```